# Robolectric: Testing with ormlite

Tags: android, testing, dao, ormlite, robolectric

I'm trying to test ORMLite DAOs with robolectric, but database behaviour is not the same as when it's used from my android app. My DAOs are working perfectly well on the android application.

Reading about robolectric shadows and debugging code, I encountered [ShadowSQLiteOpenHelper](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/javadoc/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/ShadowSQLiteOpenHelper.html) (code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.pivotallabs/robolectric/1.1/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/ShadowSQLiteOpenHelper.java?av=f)).

*Does anyone know if this Shadow is enough to test ormlite daos? Or I have to create my own shadow to achieve that? Any clue/tip/suggestion/example here?*

Thanks in advance.

---

Extra info:

Test method:

```
@Test
public void basicTest() throws SQLException {
    assertNotNull(randomStringResource); // Injection of an android resource: OK
    assertThat(randomStringResource, equalTo("Event")); // With correct value: OK
    assertNotNull(eventDao); // Dao injection: OK
    assertThat(eventDao.countOf(), equalTo(0L)); // Table empty: OK

    Event e1 = new Event("e1", new Date());
    eventDao.create(e1);

    assertNotNull(e1.getId()); // ID generated by OrmLite: OK
    assertThat(eventDao.countOf(), equalTo(1L)); // Table not empty: OK
    assertThat("e1", equalTo(eventDao.queryForId(e1.getId()).getName())); // Query for inserted event: Throws exception
}
```

Some of the problems encountered running this test:

- Errors querying entities with "camelCased" property names: error thrown at last line of test ([related problem](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ormlite-android/QnOB8S5xQqo/discussion)). Never had a problem like this running the android app.
- When I changed one of these properties name (e.g., `isEnabled` to `enabled`) in order to avoid the camelCase problem, the previous error persisted... seems like memory database didn't apply the changes that I made on the entity.

Versions used:

- Robolectric 1.1
- OrmLite 4.41

Comment: So what is the name of the event if not `"e1"`?

Comment: I assume you are using Sqlite for your tests.  I would not think the camelcase stuff was a problem unless you generated your own schema and a db field name did not match the Java -- case sensitive.

Comment: @Gray at this point, test crashes with a exception when query is going to retrieve saved event. QueryForId didn't work because the "camelCase error" is thrown.

Comment: @Gray You are correct, I'm using SQLite and schema is generated automatically from `MyDatabaseHelper.onCreate(..)` (which extends `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`), with `TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Event.class);`.

Comment: This is going to be hard to do this way.  Can you contact me here: http://256.com/gray/ or post this on the ORMLite user mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ormlite-user

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gray for your time! I'll post there too! :) But maybe the problem here would be robolectric? Ormlite works like a charm when I run the android application. Unfortunately, it's not the same when I run the tests with robolectric. I don't have experience with it but `ShadowSQLiteOpenHelper` class seems very simple for me... It's like a basic support to SQLite databases, but without ORMLite.

Comment: You might want to post on the Android list to see if anyone has done this before.  If it is still having case issues, I suspect ORMLite problems here although I don't understand Robolectric: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ormlite-android

Comment: Hey @Gray! Nope, I asked in robolectric google group with no luck :( If I finally resolve this, I will post solution here. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Jelies, can you accept the answer that flav gave? It works nicely for me.

Comment: @jelies can you post the solution here so people who face this issue can resolve by looking at your solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for resurrecting your topic but I ran into the same problem.

I'm using OrmLite 4.45 and Robolectric 2.1.

In [ShadowSQLiteCursor.java](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowSQLiteCursor.java), `cacheColumnNames` method calls `toLowerCase` on each column name. So I decided to extend `ShadowSQLiteCursor` with my own (which doesn't call `toLowerCase`):

```
/**
* Simulates an Android Cursor object, by wrapping a JDBC ResultSet.
*/
@Implements(value = SQLiteCursor.class, inheritImplementationMethods = true)
public class ShadowCaseSensitiveSQLiteCursor extends ShadowSQLiteCursor {

private ResultSet resultSet;

public void __constructor__(SQLiteCursorDriver driver, String editTable, SQLiteQuery query) {}

/**
 * Stores the column names so they are retrievable after the resultSet has closed
 */
private void cacheColumnNames(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        columnNameArray = new String[columnCount];
        for(int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            String cName = metaData.getColumnName(columnIndex);
            this.columnNames.put(cName, columnIndex - 1);
            this.columnNameArray[columnIndex - 1] = cName;
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("SQL exception in cacheColumnNames", e);
    }
}
}
```

My answer obviously comes too late but may help others!

Comment: It did help me. I added 
@Config( shadows = {ShadowCaseSensitiveSQLiteCursor.class})     to my test class